# Weights in Deep Neural Network don't change while bias change a lot. Why?

Tags: tensorflow, parameters, deep-learning

Here is the result from tensorboard. hyperlinks.

As we saw, the [loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA1Yp.png) has decreased and the [Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp7H9.png) (both train and test) has increased. Hence, the model has already been trained successfully.

However, [Distribution of parameters, weights/bias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Wt8.png) doesn't change (might change little), while the bias change a lot.
Could someone help me to explain what causes this ?
I knew this is normal result but why?
Thank you!

Could someone share the experience of training Deep Neural network?
what will be the real expectation of changing for parameters in successful trained model?

Comment: Could you please try training the model without biases and see what happened. I think the mapping between feature and target is too simple. 
Morevoer, same histogram doesn't imply same value for each weights. Weights might be changing but it is not reflected in histogram.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I will try the first suggestion.For second questions, I also track the real value of weights for each iteration. I did not upload that figures. But result is the same: weights don't change much.

Comment: Your distribution of weights appears to have started with pre-trained weights. Is that correct? If so I wouldn't expect to see a difference in the overall distribution, a roughly normal distribution is an expected distribution for trained weights. Though I admit, those are suspiciously similar looking distributions, I would have expected at least some variation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I use truncated_normal with std 0.1 without pre-training. You can observe this in weight distribution part. Indeed, various of weights increased a little. Same as you, i expected the weights should change a lot. However, after i observe real value of weights for each iteration, the bias really changes a lot ,while the weights just change little. So i am confused about this.